# Ionic export as .aar

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I have an Ionic application.

There is a request from the client that he wants the ionic app run inside a native Android application that he owns.

Is there a way that I can export my Ionic app as an android library? So he can call it inside his app?

Or what would you recommend?